# Unable to set cookies with Perl and Xampp

Tags: html, perl, session, cookies, xampp

I'm using Xampp and Perl , when I try to set a cookie with CGI::Cookies or CGI::Session it prints the cookies data to the browser page instead of setting the cookie.

Example:

```
my $session = new CGI::Session();
my $cookie = CGI::Cookie->new(-name=>$session->name, -value=>$session->id);
print $session->header(-cookie=>$cookie, @_);
```

Result on the browser screen:

```
Set-Cookie: CGISESSID=cebc22d8046879efa9d0216eb8995d13; path=/
Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2014 04:34:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that you had sent the header to the browser already.

After the standard header received by browser it handles every output as text.

Regards,